# Serial Communication and Local Clock error calculation

Tags: uart

For a 24MHz system, the local clock error associated with transmitting 10-bit character frames at 38.4 Kbaud using the SCI of a Freescale Micro is 0.16%.

How? I can't figure out the math that actually makes sense to get that number. Any ideas? I'm sure it's easy.

Comment: @Keegan - you will have to let us know which Freescale part you are using to give you an accurate answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically an asynchronous communication pin is sampled at 16 times the bit rate.  This implies a baudrate generator of:

\$\frac{24000000}{16}\frac{1}{38400} = 39.0625 \$

Since the resulting integer value is 39, the resulting error is:

\$\frac{0.0625}{39.0625} = 0.0016 \$

or 0.16%

Answer (score 3):

Here's a tool (for AVR) that demonstrates the calculations. It's all about integer divison of the baud rate and system clock.

http://www.wormfood.net/avrbaudcalc.php

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the Freescale datasheet.

But 24MHz / 38400 baud is exactly 625 cycles per symbol.

I will guess that there is an unavoidable divide in the clock or baudrate generator, so the desired ratio is half of 625 or 312.5.  The closest an integer counter can come is 312.

312 is 0.16% lower than 312.5

Comment: i also do not have the datasheet. i would bet markrages is spot on.

Comment: @markrages - Could you please explain why the desired ratio is half?

Comment: it is correlated to an unavoidable hardware divide by 2.

Comment: I'd guess that the divide by two is because the hardware is oversampling the RS232 bits

Comment: @Joby, I don't believe this is correct.  For an asynchronous port such as RS232, the hardware typically oversamples by a factor of 16x, not 2x.

Comment: @semaj 2^4=16 so assuming you don't divide to be less then 1 the percent error will work out the same.

Comment: semaj is probably right.  Maybe somebody should pull up the datasheet and check?  The same error appears with oversampling ratios 2,3,4,6,8,12,13,16,24,26,39,78,156, and 312.

Comment: @Kellenjb - I agree, the percent error does work out to be the same.  Divisors of 4 and 8 would also yield the same error; however, the value of the baud rate generator is different.  I'm guessing that the OP is looking the correct formula so which divisor do you pick?  Not having the part number of data sheet to look it up, we have to guess.  All of the implementations I have worked with sample at 16x.  This could be wrong but it is my best guess.